# What does evaluating [CNContactStore class] as a boolean expression do?

Tags: ios, objective-c

While refactoring from Objective-C to Swift we came across this old piece of code with the following if statement:

```
if (![CNContactStore class]) {
    // do stuff
}
```

How can a type be used as a boolean expression? I have no idea what's going on here. I'm amazed it even compiles.

Comment: Please post what is CNCoactactStore class looks like before anyone can help you

Comment: @cole Its an Apple class, [take a look](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontactstore)

Comment: Sorry, was not aware before. But thanks for letting me know